# ARIMA(1, 1, 0) Model

Tags: time-series, arima

What is the equation for an ARIMA(1, 1, 0) Model?

Please note that I fit the model to a time series in R and received an "ar1" coefficient of 0.6017 and that was the only coefficient estimate provided by R.

Answer (score 2):

For base R the equation for an ARIMA(1,1,0) model is

$\Delta Y_t = \alpha_1 \Delta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$,

where $\Delta Y_t = Y_t - Y_{t-1}$ and the mean is subtracted from every observation, such that $\Delta Y_t = (Y_t - \mu)-(Y_{t-1}-\mu)$.

The second "1" in ARIMA(1,1,0) tells you that you are taking first differences between $Y_t$ and $Y_{t-1}$. This is done when $Y_t$ shows evidence of non-stationarity, which disappears when taking first differences.

Your `ar1` coefficient is the estimate of the coefficient on the lagged first difference, and is the first "1" in ARIMA(1,1,0).

Comment: Note that $Y_t - Y_{t-1} = (Y_t - \mu)-(Y_{t-1}-\mu)$.